# postgresql cache and swap memory increasing

Tags: performance, postgresql, memory, database-tuning

I have postgresql(Master and Slave) infrastructure. The postgresql server have 32 GB RAM and 600 MB swap space. We are using java(tomcat) applications. I have performed postgresql tuning using http://pgtune.leopard.in.ua/. But currently my issue is, my postgresql server caching and swap memory increasing periodically and certain point we forced to clear the cache or restart the postgresql. Could you please let me with the reason behind it. Below are my performance tuning parameter. Rest of the parameters are default. Also we are using pgbarman to take the point of time backup which configure on other server.

```
postgresql.conf
===============
  max_connections = 300
  shared_buffers = 8GB
  effective_cache_size = 24GB
  work_mem = 27962kB
  maintenance_work_mem = 2GB
  checkpoint_segments = 32
  checkpoint_completion_target = 0.7
  wal_buffers = 16MB
  default_statistics_target = 100 

/etc/sysctl.conf
================
kernel.shmmax=17179869184
kernel.shmall=4194304
```

Comment: What do you mean by "server caching memory" and how are you measuring that?

Comment: ave checked the buffere+cachng memory using free command. prash@postgresmaster ~$ free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:      32632272   32234640     397632          0      72652   30869084
-/+ buffers/cache:    1292904   31339368
Swap:       688124      67164     620960

Comment: I don't think this is really a problem. You would expect a process to use kernel cache memory if nothing else is running on the system.

Comment: The issue is after some period of time(May after 15 days), system swap space get filled and system will go for a "Out of Memory" . Is there any way we can specifically declare the buffer memory limit for postgres process.

Comment: Seems like this more of an issue with the instance you are running on not your postgres db.